# How to separate my code to many method?

Tags: android, wifi

I am a new in android developing, I've code to connect to server and send commands,
How to separate connection code in method and sending code in another method.
my code as following:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Socket socket = null;
 DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
 DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

 try {  
// connect code         
  socket = new Socket("172.16.149.64", 8888);

// sending code
  dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
  dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());
  textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
 } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 finally{

  if (dataOutputStream != null){
   try {
    dataOutputStream.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  if (dataInputStream != null){
   try {
    dataInputStream.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  if (socket != null){
       try {
        socket.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }

 }
}
```

Comment: my problem that sending code calls (socket.getOutputStream()) which is in another method.

Answer (score 0):

Write a class of your own and make the `Socket` one of its member variables. You can then write `connect()` and `sendData()` methods to your class using the same socket in both methods.

Comment: Please, I'm beginner I'll need to more details to do that.

Comment: how to call connect() and sendData() from main class?

Comment: It is a matter of dividing your program to classess that address separate concerns. Please refer to any tutorial on object oriented design. I can't address your specific problem here in further detail.

Comment: thank you. i did that but when I separate `socket = new Socket("172.16.149.64", 8888)` in method then it doesn't work.